# Looping through a directory, importing and processing text files in a chronology order using Python

Tags: python, loops, text, import

Hoping I could get help with my python code, currently I have to change the working directory manually every time I run my code that loops through all the .txt files in chronological order, since they are numbered **1_Ix_100.txt**, **2_Ix_99.txt** etc etc until **201_Ix_-100.txt**. all the text files are in the same directory i.e. C:/test/Ig=*/340_TXT what changes is the starred folder which goes from 340 to 1020 in increments of 40 i.e. C:/test/**Ig=340**/340_TXT, C:/test/**Ig=380**/340_TXT etc etc etc until C:/test/**Ig=1020**/340_TXT.

I'm looking for a way to automate this process so that the code loops through the different /Ig=***/ folder, process the text files and save the outcome as csv file in the /*Ig=*/

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re
import os
import glob
D = []
E = []
F = []
os.chdir('C:/test/**Ig=700**/340_TXT') #Need to loop through the different folders in bold, these go from Ig=340 to Ig=1020 in incruments of 40 
numbers = re.compile(r'(\d+)')
def numericalSort(value):
    parts = numbers.split(value)
        parts[1::2] = map(int, parts[1::2])
        return parts
for infile in sorted(glob.glob('*.txt'), key=numericalSort):
       name=['1', '2']
       results = pd.read_table(infile, sep='\s+', names=name)


        #process files here with output [D], [E], [F]


       ArrayMain = []
       ArrayMain = np.column_stack((D,E,F)) 
       np.savetxt("C:/test/**Ig=700**/Grey_Zone.csv", ArrayMain, delimiter=",", fmt='%.9f') #save output in this directory which is one less than the   working directory
```

I really hope the way I have worded it makes sense and I appreciate any help at all, thank you

Comment: please accept one of the answers if they have been helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a simple loop and some string manipulation you can create a list of the paths you want and then iterate over them.

```
Ig_txts = []
i=340
while i <= 1020:
    Ig_txts.append( 'Ig='+str(i) )
    i += 40

for Ig_txt in Ig_txts:
    path = 'C:/test/'+Ig_txt+'/340_TXT'
    out_file = 'C:/test/'+Ig_txt+'/Grey_Zone.csv'

    os.chdir(path)
    ...
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Gabriel brought up that my range is a little off. Check the second code blurb for the modification.

I would first put your script into a function that takes, as one of its arguments, a `path`. The details are up to you, this code just details how to loop through the file names.

```
for root, _, files in os.walk('C:/test/'):
    for f in files:
        os.chdir(os.path.join(root, f))
        #You now have the paths you need to open, close, etc.
```

Now, if there are other garbage files in `'C:/test/'`, then you could use a range based loop:

```
min_file_num = 340
max_file_num = 1020
for dir_num in range(min_file_num, max_file_num+1, 40):
   path = 'C:/test/Ig=' + str(dir_num) + '/'
   for root, _, files in os.walk(path):
       for f in files:
        os.chdir(os.path.join(root, f))
        #You now have the paths you need to open, close, etc.
```

Comment: just a heads up, the for loop will not produce the last value `dir_num = 1020` here. you can do `for dir_num in range(340, 1021, 40):` and it will.  range goes up to but not including the upper limit.